# An example of a well-formed class definition with a defaulted special member function that the compiler makes deleted

Tags: c++, class, default, c++20, function-definition

In the C++20 standard, [[dcl.fct.def.default]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def.default), Explicitly-defaulted functions:

> 2 The type `T1` of an explicitly defaulted special member function `F` is
>   allowed to differ from the type `T2` it would have had if it were
>   implicitly declared, as follows:
>
> (2.1) — `T1` and `T2` may have differing ref-qualifiers;
>
> (2.2) — `T1` and `T2` may have differing exception specifications; and
>
> (2.3) — if `T2` has a parameter of type `const C&`, the corresponding
>   parameter of `T1` may be of type `C&`.
>
> If `T1` differs from `T2` in any other way, then:
>
> (2.4) — if `F` is an assignment operator, and the return type of `T1`
>   differs from the return type of `T2` or `T1`’s parameter type is not a
>   reference, the program is ill-formed;
>
> (2.5) — **otherwise, if `F` is explicitly defaulted on its first
>   declaration, it is defined as deleted;**
>
> (2.6) — otherwise, the program is ill-formed

Could anybody provide an example of a special member function explicitly defaulted and that is deleted by the compiler. The function declaration should be well-formed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example from [P0641](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0641r2.html), whence this wording:

```
struct MyType {
  MyType(MyType&);  // no 'const'
};

template <typename T>
struct Wrapper {
  Wrapper(const Wrapper&) = default;
  T t;
};

Wrapper<MyType> var;  // fails to instantiate
```

Pretend there was actually a default constructor.

This was previously ill-formed. Now, `T1` (`Wrapper`'s copy constructor) differs from it what it would have been were it implicitly declared (would have been `Wrapper(Wrapper&)` per [[class.copy.ctor]/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.ctor#7)). This doesn't match the cases in the first set of bullets (here `T1` has `const&` but not `T2`, the bullet is in the opposite order), so we fall through to the second set of bullets - and we end up with `Wrapper<MyType>`'s copy constructor being deleted.

---

A good example of where this would've come up in code is something like `std::tuple` (see [LWG2086](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2068)), where prior to these changes:

```
struct A {
  A();
  A(A&);
};
std::tuple<A> x; // ill-formed
```

Now, this is well-formed, just that `tuple<A>` isn't copyable.